# Parametric representation of a solid trapezoid

Tags: geometry, parametric

Question: Define a parametrical representation of a solid trapezoid as shown in the following figure:

[image: Figure 1]

I came up with a solution by combining representations of the left rectangle and the right triangle
$x=u$

$y=\frac{v}{-2}(\frac{|u|}{u}-1)+\frac{v}{2}(\frac{|u|}{u}+1)(1-u)(1-v)$

$-1 \leq u \leq 1 $

$0 \leq v \leq 1 $

Is there any simpler representation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your representation focused on $x$ (made its equation completely simple). Let us instead focus on $y$:

$$x=u(2-v)-1$$
$$y=v$$
$$0\le u\le 1,\ 0\le v\le 1$$

Comment: As you were implicitly cited in the recent question : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3218523 you will find in my answer to this question a general framework for your answer (bilinear interpolation) and another one which is projective geometry.