# How to calculate a volume of a solid with four different corner depths

Tags: volume, solid-geometry

I'm currently trying to calculate the volume of a relatively rectangular solid where all four corner points are at different depths. I'm aware it's probably a pretty simple solution, but for some reason my brain just isn't working this morning.

I've drawn a rough sketch of the appearance of the shape

[image]

The sides with matching colours are the same lengths.

Any help would be *greatly* appreciated, and I thank you so much.

Comment: Are the basis points on a same plane ? Do they constitute a rectangle ? Are the vertical-looking line segments really vertical ? [If the basis is a rectangle, I doubt it is possible that the violet lengths are the same].

Comment: The vertical line segments are truly vertical. It doesn't need to be an exact answer, so I'm taking the assumption that the violet lines are close enough to be the same. 

Also, please take the image as flipped, the ground level is the one with different depths. Sorry!

Comment: I don't entirely understand your diagram and description.  (1) It seems unlikely that the purple sides are all the same length as they are not parallel. (Similarly for the black sides.) (2) Are the red, green, orange, and brown sides perpendicular to the lower base? (3) Four points in  space don't generally lie in a plane...is the upper side planar?

Comment: I'm sorry I'm not being entirely clear with this. Imagine a rectangular swimming pool with an increasing depth, except instead of the two points on the far size being the deepest ones, all of the four points are at a different depth. Is that description any better?

Comment: I'll assume all the angles at the top vertices are right angles, and also that the bottom face is a flat plane (but not level). Then you can just take the average lengths of the four vertical edges (or just the average of two diagonally opposite vertical edges), and act as if you have a rectangular block of that height. The volume is that average height times the area of the top face.

Comment: Be aware that in general, this has no unique solution, because the slanted face is not flat (or 'planar'). You can choose the four corner heights to make it flat, and if this is an upside-down swimming pool, that is a reasonable condition to impose. You need simply green + brown = red + orange.

Comment: So lines with matching colors are not all exactly the same length. Only the ones on the top face are equal. You could say instead, the top face is a perfect rectangle and perfectly horizontal, the four vertical edges are perfectly vertical (i.e., perpendicular to the top face, and the bottom face is all in one plane, but not parallel to the top face.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

let $AB=h_1,EF=h_2,GD=h_3, HC = h_4$ , Let $AHGF$ be a rectangle base with $AH=l \ and \ AF=b.$

(I know the diagram is not clear but as you can see I am trying to cut figure by a plane which is prependicular to $AHGF$ and have a thickness $dx$)

lets say plane cuts $BC\ at\ K , ED\ at \ L, AH\ at\ M, GF \ at \ N.$

So $MK= h_1+(h_4-h_1)\frac{x}{l}=t(x)$ and $NL=h_2+(h_3-h_2)\frac{x}{l}=s(x).$

So the area of the trapezium $'KLMN'=\frac{s(x)+t(x)}{2}b$

So the required volume is $\int_0^l [\frac{s(x)+t(x)}{2} \times b]dx$

So final answer is $\frac{h_1+h_2+h_3+h_4}{4}lb$(as the $@ 'Jaap Scherphuis'$ said)

Comment: You really need [one of these](https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&source=images&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjK5tDruqbnAhUtxYUKHXlNDIAQjRx6BAgBEAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.indiamart.com%2Fproddetail%2Ftransparent-ruler-18980139830.html&psig=AOvVaw3-yDPZ0g0dmdo18Y-AQQku&ust=1580306549369451), aryan!

Comment: yeah may be 

Comment: I am sorry but your "final answer" (which is exact : I have obtained the same one) doesn't easily follow from the lines before.

Comment: i don't get you, could you explain

Answer (score 0):

If you have a box with rectangular basis $A \times B$, with coordinates

$$(0,0,0),(A,0,0), (0,B,0), (A,B,0),$$

and corresponding upper corners at

$$(0,0,p),(A,0,q),(0,B,r),(A,B,s)$$

(these ones being non-coplanar in general).

you can "fit" on it the following second degree surface with equation :

$$z=\dfrac{1}{AB}\left(p(A-x)(B-y)+qx(B-y)+r(A-x)B+sxy\right) \tag{1}$$

(it works almost magically : take for example the case where $x=A$ and $y=0$ : only one term survives, the term $qx(B-y)$ whose value in this case is $qAB$, which finally gives $q$ because of the division by factor $AB$).

Now, the volume is very easy to obtain by integrating (1).
All computations done, (see remark below).

one obtains :

> $$V=AB\dfrac14(p+q+r+s)$$

See a figure in a [previous answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3219000).

This technique is called **bilinear interpolation**. The skew surface $z=f(x,y)$ given by (1) is called a hyperbolic paraboloid (which is a ruled surface).

Remark : Example of integration :$$\int_{x=0}^{x=A} \int_{y=0}^{y=B} pxy dx dy \ = \ p[\dfrac{x^2}{2}]_0^{A}[\dfrac{y^2}{2}]_0^{B} \ = \ p\dfrac{A^2}{2}\dfrac{B^2}{2}.$$